# Is it possible to write cross-platform drive mappings in Docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

At work developers generally use Windows, servers are typically Linux. We have a shared drive that a lot of legacy applications depend on. On Windows the shared drive is mapped as `S:`, and on Linux it's `/mnt/s`.

I have a docker-compose file written for Linux, it looks a bit like this:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mysvc:
    build:
      target: myimg
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./src:/src"
      - "/mnt/s:/mnt/s"
```

This works just fine on Linux, but it doesn't work at all on Windows, because `/mnt/s` is a UNIX style path.

Is there a way I can provide an alternative path for Windows users, but without having to provide an entirely different Compose file? I'd like to only have to maintain a single file.